# CSS or XPath selector for successive elements

Tags: html, css, xpath

Is there a CSS or XPath selector for successive elements? I want to test some HTML to ensure a sequence of `<h1>` to `<h6>` Tags. I want to make sure that there are no missing headers. For example this would be valid

```
<h1>Header1</h1>
<h2>Header2</h2>
<h3>Header3</h3>
```

but this would be invalid

```
<h1>Header1</h1>
<h3>Header3</h3>
<h4>Header4</h4>
```

because the `<h2>` tag is missing.

The problem is, that I also want to treat this HTML als valid, but haven't found a selector that can select the `<h2>` tag:

```
<h1>Header1</h1>
<div>
  <h2>Header2</h2>
</div>
<h3>Header3</h3>
```

I tried it with siblings `h1~h2~h3` but this doesn't work in the nested case. I tried the adjacent selector `h1+h2+h3` but this doesn't work either. It seems that there are only child selectors, and stuff that operates on the same parent level. I also tried using XPath for the problem, but it seems that there a similar limitation than in CSS.

So is there a "element is after another element somewhere in the code" kind of selector either in CSS or XPath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XPath you can use `following` axis to select following node that might not be a sibling:

```
//h1/following::h2/following::h3/following::h4/following::h5/following::h6
```